# Notification for each transaction in a database

Tags: java, database, push-notification, real-time

I am trying to build a push notification system.My requirement is whenever a DB entry is updated i need a push notification should send to the customer.

I have implemented the same using the Google FireBase.I need to have it in local for getting the full control.is there any real time database available as opensource for implementing the same?

Or is there any alternate way to implement the same?

Comment: Finally i found something called Rethink DB , i think it would help..

Comment: Are you using Spring ?

Comment: Yes spring-boot 2.0

Comment: Did my answer fix it for ya ?

Comment: I am trying it out..hope it will fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Spring integration. You can use a `@Router` channel when persisting to DB. the `@Router` channel will forward your routing request to the DB and to another channel for notifying the customer.

```
@Router(inputChannel="persistingAndNotifyingCustomerChannel")
public String[] route(Object payload) {
   return Arrays.AsList("persistingChannel", "notifyingCutomerChannel");
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "persistingChannel")
public void persist(Object payload) {
    // persist
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "notifyingCutomerChannel")
public void notify(Object payload) {
    // notify
}
```